# Laravel Nova creating a model with an action in newModel()

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm in Laravel 8 with Nova 3.22. I have a table that contains a field that is populated automatically with a serial number inside a DB transaction, and in order to enforce that I have a `CreateProduct` action defined that wraps the creation of that resource. Everywhere I need to create a new instance of that model, I call the action, and I need to do the same in Nova. I've found the `newModel()` method to override, but it has two problems.

```php
    public static function newModel()
    {
        $instance = new CreateProduct(
            new \App\Models\Sku(), //Placeholder
            \App\Models\Product::STATUS_DEFAULT,
            null
        );

        return $instance->handle();
    }
```

Firstly, this method is called on `create` (displaying the input form) as well as `store` store operations. This means I end up with two calls to my action, creating spurious serial numbers in my DB. If I *don't* override `newModel` like this, it creates records that lack a serial number altogether. I have a choice of 0 or 2 calls, but I only want 1!

The second issue is related; when the form is displayed, it calls `newModel`, but I have to use placeholder data for required params of the action, as those fields have (obviously) not been set yet, but I need to replace those placeholders with the real submitted values the second time, and I'm not sure how I would do that.

I feel I must be missing something – is there something like `newModel`, but that is only called for a `store` operation?

Comment: I've not found a clean solution to this, but I have found a workaround. Disable the `create` button in Nova using a `authorizedToCreate` method that returns `false`, then create a Nova action that gives me a chance to use my wrapper. This has the added advantage that it lets me create multiple instances in one go, and also do so via a queue.